# Dereferencing possible?

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
public class Test {

    static private volatile Integer number1 = 42;
    static private volatile Integer number2 = 42;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.changeInteger(number1);
        System.out.println(number1);
    }

    public void changeInteger (Integer number) {
        number = new Integer(3);
    }
}
```

I would like to change the value of either `number1` or `number2` depending on the argument I pass to the method `changeInteger`. Obviously this doesn't work. Is there a way to make this work in Java without using reflection?

To clarify: I want the call `changeInteger(number1)` to change the field `number1`.

Comment: You have several choices, use an array, use an if/else statement, use a switch statement..  however, more importantly, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: @ChrisK My actual code is a bit more complicated. The fields are actual WeakRerences that will be accessed by multiple threads through a double checked locking pattern. So I want an easy way to parameterize which field is going to be updated.

Comment: @Roland in that case you may be served best by a simple Map, mapping the 'field name' to the 'field value'.

Comment: @Roland but to answer your question, yes the fields can be selected dynamically without using reflection in Java by using Unsafe.  Frankly I would change the design or use reflection at that point ;)

Comment: In Java 8 one can use method references, which is nicer. That would involve storing the field name and the reference in a map. So once again, not great.

Comment: @ChrisK What do you mean by Unsafe?

Comment: @Roland ua-ooo, can of worms ;)  sun.misc.Unsafe, is a back door into a lot of low level goodies in Java.. it is an interesting area to research, but be warned.. mis-use of it can crash the JVM.

Comment: @ChrisK wow, first time ever I learn about this. Thanks for the link, but I agree this is probably not a good idea.

Comment: A simple `if` statement would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to @Margus's answer.
In my books, if a variable name *ever* contains a number, like `number1`, that's a sign that you aren't doing it right. Use an array.

On the other hand, if your variables are actually **named**, you may be better of using a `Hashtable`. 
The names of fields in a class are meant to be hard-coded. If you ever need non-hard-coded  "field names", then they aren't really fields. They are data! So hashtable / dictionary is the correct route in Java.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Test {
    public Integer[] number = {42, 42};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();             //you create a new instance
        test.number[0] = new Integer(3);    //change first element to 3
        test.number[1] = new Integer(2);    //change second element to 2
        System.out.println(test.number[0]); //print first element
    }
}
```

About arrays: [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
Demo : http://ideone.com/aKzQI0

Answer (score 2):

You will need to return the value of the variable from the method. Otherwise the change in value of variable is restricted the method call stack of 'changeInteger' method.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        number1 = test.changeInteger(number1);
        System.out.println(number1);
    }

    public Integer changeInteger (Integer number) {
        return new Integer(3);
    }
```